# Clearing map cache - ArcGIS Engine

Tags: arcgis-10.0, c#, arcgis-engine, cache

Is there a programmatic way to clear the cache of a map in ArcGIS Engine 10.0?

It is apparent that there is some caching scheme operating under the covers, and I'd like to clear all of its cached data.  To be clear it isn't *leaking* memory, I just don't want it to be caching anything.

This is a fairly vanilla (*.mxd).  Just a raster dataset, no basemap layers or anything fancy going on.

[image: graph of memory]

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the [IMapCooker2 Interface](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//001200000861000000). It has two methods for clearing caches, [Clear](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Clear_Method/00120000086v000000/) and [ClearAll](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/ClearAll_Method/00120000086w000000/).

[Clear](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Clear_Method/00120000086v000000/) clears the cache for a given layer within a given extent.

```
public void Clear (
    ILayer pLayer,
    IEnvelope pExtent
);
```

[ClearAll](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/ClearAll_Method/00120000086w000000/) on the other hand, clears cache for all layers.

```
public void ClearAll (
);
```

Comment: -1 According to the [documentation](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IDynamicCacheLayerManager_Interface/00120000041s000000/), "The Interface IDynamicCacheLayerManager was written in order to manage the caches of proprietary dynamic display caches and it should not be used to manage MapServerLayers or **rasters**)"